# My Local Development Environment got misconfigured after Falls Creators Update

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I had just updated to falls creators update, I was working fine with Creators update before but when i got the new update.

My local environment got misconfigured, now I can't test my app locally. I don't understand why I get this error message:

> Unable to start debugging on the Web server, The remote server returned an error[503] service unavailable.

I found on this page this: [(503) Server Unavailable. The Application Pool may have stopped due to an error or configuration change. Restart the Application Pool.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.debug.error.http)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6)%26rd%3Dtrue#server_error)

Now I don't now how to restart it, and I had follow up this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Local-development-and-debugging-the-Mobile-App-.NET-server-backend) to set again my local environment but apparently, everything looks fine.

Hopefully someone can help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to solve it.
I had configured my local server correctly since anniversary update at windows 10, when I updated to Creator Update it still worked fine, but recently here in Mexico i was offered to update to Fall Creators Update so I decided to update it.

after the update IIS Manager was uninstall from my OS, so I used WEB Plataform Installer from windows and reinstall it after it I could notice that my app user DefaultAppPool stopped even after I used at command prompt with administrator privileges so I create a new Application Pool with .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319 and Managed Pipeline mode: Integrated.

after that i used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I logged in to my local database and created a new user for my app, using as a user the App pool i just created and that did the trick.

After it I was able to made my backend work in debug mode in my local server and my client make its queries to my local server getting everything to as it was before.

Hopefully if somebody suffers the same experience as i did, this serves you as a solution for your local development enviroment.

Comment: Glad to know that this issue has been resolved, thanks for your sharing, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)